# Set HYDRA's parameter HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1

Tags: python, conda

When I tried to run a python script in conda environment using "python my_script.py", I encountered this error: "Set the environment variable HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1 for a complete stack trace."

How to set this variable in conda environment?

I tried adding the argument "HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1" in the commands but it won't recognize "HYDRA_FULL_ERROR".

Comment: Hello. Have you seen [this](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables) link from the Conda documentation on how to set environment variables? If not, give that a try, and if it still doesn't work, update your question with the latest information on what you tried and what your output is.

Comment: `HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1 python my_script.py`

Comment: `set HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1` works! Or construct .bat files as this [link](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables) suggests also works.